# ASP.NET Core 2.1 API Caching

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

In my ASP.NET Core 2.1 API app, I have a few endpoints that return fairly static user data e.g. user avatar, etc.

I've already implemented Redis cache to save myself a trip to the database but I'd like to implement one more layer of caching to help reduce hits on my Redis cache as well.

What additional options do I have to cache some of this data so that I don't even have to go to Redis, unless I have to?

BTW, my app runs on Azure App Service so I don't have any control over server resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of Asp.Net Core response caching by specifying the Cache-Control in your response header also Asp.Net Core supports `AddMemoryCache` which can be configured in Startp through dependency injection

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

This resource explains the various ways you can implement caching in Asp.Net Core 2.1

[REFERENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful! According to the document, I can't use `AddMemoryCache()` because I'm running my app on Azure App Service but response caching is what I was looking for.